# PTIJ: What did Rav Yehuda say that caused Rav Zeira to become Haredi?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemora in Brakhot 53b says:

> אָמַר רַבִּי זֵירָא: מֵרֵישׁ הֲוָה מְהַדַּרְנָא, כֵּיוָן דִּשְׁמַעְנָא
>   לְהָא דְּרַב יְהוּדָה אָמַר רַב, אֲנָא נָמֵי לָא מְהַדַּרְנָא.
>
> Rav Zeira said: Initially I was modern [orthodox], once I heard this teaching
>   that Rav Yehuda said in the name of Rav, I am no longer modern [rather, I am haredi]

What was it that caused Rav Zeira to change his ways?

Comment: Are you sure Rav Yehuda was Charedi? Maybe he was a liberal...

Comment: Probably all the fasts

Answer (score 6):

It's simple. R. Zeira heard a statement of Rav Yehuda which caused him to become an anti-Zionist, and he was therefore no longer able to [identify as Modern Orthodox](https://web.archive.org/web/20041216072651/http://www.mizrachi.org/ideas/view.asp?id=122).

What did he learn from Rav Yehuda? The statement taught in [Berachot 24b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.24b.8?lang=bi):

> אָמַר רַב יְהוּדָה: כׇּל הָעוֹלֶה מִבָּבֶל לְאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל — עוֹבֵר בַּעֲשֵׂה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״בָּבֶלָה יוּבָאוּ וְשָׁמָּה יִהְיוּ עַד יוֹם פׇּקְדִי אוֹתָם נְאֻם ה׳״‏
>
> Rav Yehuda said: Anyone who ascends from Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael transgresses a positive commandment, as it is stated: “They shall be taken to Babylonia and there they shall remain until the day that I recall them, said the Lord”.

Although the statement there is said by Rav Yehuda and not attributed to Rav, it must be that Rav Yehuda did in fact learn his anti-Zionism from Rav (as implied by the quote you bring from Berachot 53b). We know that Rav was an anti-Zionist, because he made *[yeridah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yerida)* to Bavel, as discussed in [Sanhedrin 5a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.5a.11?lang=bi).

Comment: This was my first thought as well. Though if I recall correctly, in one of the versions of the story (not the one in Berachos) the amora that was hiding from R. Yehuda in order to go to Israel was actually R. Zera.